# odoo - enable CORS to make a ajax

Tags: ajax, cors, odoo

I need to do a ajax to odoo 8 server  but the response of the ajax is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. To be able to realize it I need to enable CORS.
Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you can change the server side code**

The method you are trying to call remotely has a http.request decorator. I guess it looks something like

```
@http.route('/example', type='http', auth='public', website=True)
def render_example_page(self):
    ...
```

this decorater has a parameter *cors*. You can set a specific URI from which requests should be allowed or you can set it to * to allow request from all origins.

```
@http.route('/example', type='http', auth='public', website=True, cors='*')
```